# Dirty state for forms considering Collection properties

Tags: java, zk

I have the following model:

Person

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private Set<Phone> phones;
    // setters and getters
}
```

My ViewModel has following filds:

```
public class PersonViewModel {

    private Person selected;
    private Phone selectedPhone;

    // setters and getters for fields

    @Command
    public void save() {
        // basically persists selected field
    }

    // additional commands

}
```

My View will create a form like:

```
<groupbox form="@id('fx') @load(vm.selected) @save(vm.selected, before='save')">
```

and will expose the name in a textbox and the phones on a listbox. Everytime I selected a phone I set the property selectedPhone. The phone can be edited by using another textfields on my view.

When I change the name the dirty state of my form is updated, and this is good. When I select a Phone I can see that the property selectedPhone of my viewmodel is set. But when I change the phone using the editBox bounded to selectedPhone the dirty state of my form doesn't changed.

This is expected since I'm changing the ViewModel and not the form. But what would be the way to solve this problem, since when a phone is changed, means the Person is changed too, because there are things to save?

The view implementation is like this:

```
...
<groupbox form="@id('fx') @load(vm.selected) @save(vm.selected, before='save')" vflex="1">
    <textbox width="50px" value="@bind(fx.name)" />
    <listbox vflex="true" model="@load(fx.phones)" selectedItem="@bind(vm.selectedPhone)">
        <!-- shows the phone record -->
    </listbox>
    <textbox width="50px" value="@bind(vm.selectedPhone.number)" />
</groupbox>
....
```

When I change the name it updates the form (fx) and its state is dirty. But changing the selectedPhone.number it doesn't pass the form and due this reason it isn't marked as dirty. Phones is a collection, how shall it be handle to present within the GUI and mark the entire form as dirty if a property from phone that is contained in the collection of fx is changed?

Comment: Please define "dirty" for me, cos I don't get what's your problem.

Comment: Take a look in the documentation of [FormImpl#isDirty](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/bind/impl/FormImpl.html#isDirty%28%29). But dirty state means something that was already changed from its initial state, for example a bean that was loaded and has one of its property changed (but not committed) by the user.

Comment: I edited my awnser, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking a bit about the situation, for me there is a simple solution,
just add an additional object, cos your problem is that you don't access `fx`,
so we just make a container so you have a new `fx` which is accessed when you change something in your collection.

```
public class MyPersonContainer {
  private Person selected;
  private Phone selectedPhone;
  //getter/setter
}
```

and change your VM

```
public class PersonViewModel {
   //private Person selected;
   //private Phone selectedPhone;
   private MyPersonContainer container;
   ...
}
```

as well as your view

```
<groupbox form="@id('fx') @load(vm.container) @save(vm.container, before='save')">
<listbox vflex="true" model="@load(fx.selected.phones)" selectedItem="@bind(fx.selectedPhone)">
...
<textbox width="50px" value="@bind(fx.selectedPhone.number)" />
```

Comment: I added additional comment, the problem isn't the notification but how shall collections be handled in a form.

Comment: In fact it isn't that simple, if you take a look into the question you will see I'm number property from phone which is in a collection that is referred by a property of person that is used by vm, it should be more or less like: @bind(vm.selected.phones[?].number) and I can't handle this manually, if I shall do this manually its easier to use another approach then VMMV. And as far as I can see there is no such binding for this situation right?

Comment: Thanks Nabil! I implemented like this after a lot of tries... it isn't as I expected but better than current solution ;)